# compare similarity between users PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, percentage, similarity

i'm making a site with a user system
and want to match users by their profile which have like 20 fields

i want that users can get a match with an other user when they are above 50% which is 10 fields of the 20 the same

i already got this:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='test'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query);
    $array = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='test2'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query2);
    $array2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);

    $similar = array_intersect($array, $array2);
    $p2_perc = count($similar) / count($array2);

    echo round($p2_perc * 100) . "% equal";
```

i want that the users will automatically get that specific user displayed but i can fix that

anyone ?

thanks in advance
appreciated very much!

the real question is like this

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1";
if ($query2 similarity > 50%)
echo "$user2";
```

Comment: where's the question?

Comment: And what works/doesn't work? That seems like it could work..but its hard to see where it is failing

Comment: this code above works with showing the percentage of the similarity with both users but i want to make the query2 $query2 = "SELECT * FROM users"; so it will only select the users who are more then 50% similar

Comment: its depends to your users table's columns I think?

Comment: Can you clarify?  Are you searching for any user who's "similar" to a particular user whose identity you know in advance?  Or are you intending to scan through all pairs of users looking for the ones that match most closely>

Comment: The world is already overrun with dating sites, all of them spamming me on a daily basis... do we really need another?

Comment: Oof, I can't think of a way to do this that won't result in a Cartesian join.  You'll be looking at `user`^2 number of results records that have to be thinned out.

Comment: @MarkBaker this is not a dating site it's something else :P but the idea of it is to match every row of the logged in user with all the users and only show the users who have 50% matched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine this into one query like this:

```
SELECT
    user1.username,
    user2.username,
    (
        (user1.row1=user2.row1) + 
        (user1.row2=user2.row2) +
        ...
    )/20 AS score
FROM
    users AS user1,
    users AS user2
WHERE
    user1.username <> user2.username
HAVING
    score > 0.5
```

This returns the two usernames and their score only it the score is greater than 0.5,

Explanation: The two columns get compared (each of the `user1.rowX=user2.rowX`). If they're the same, it's `1`, else `0`. The sum of the 0's and 1's gets divided by the number of questions (20) and this is the score (it's a simple calculation of the average).

But this might get quite slow if you check a lot of users. If you want to display the matches only for a given user (e.g. who is logged in currently) use:

```
SELECT
    user1.username,
    user2.username,
    (
        (user1.row1=user2.row1) + 
        (user1.row2=user2.row2) +
        ...
    )/20 AS score
FROM
    users AS user1,
    users AS user2
WHERE
    user1.username <> user2.username AND
    user1.username = 'CURRENTLY_LOGGED_IN_USER'
HAVING
    score > 0.5
```

Comment: Hello i think this will work can you help me with something tho ? i want to compare the users testing and derping with the rows equal1, equal2, equal3 & equal4 i'm pretty sleepy so if you could help me with that ? and what if i want to compare the CURRENTLY_LOGGED_IN_USER with all the users(*) and get the users who are 50% or more matched THANKS

Comment: My first query checks every user against every other. The second one checks the CURRENTLY_LOGGED_IN_USER against all others and returns the users with a score greater than 0.5 (50 percent). So the second query answers your second question. If you only want to check two users, add them in the WHERE clause.

Comment: so it would look like something like this ? or is this incorrect? not workin
        
        $query = "SELECT
        test.username,
        baro.username,
        (
        (test.option1=baro.option1) + 
        (test.gender=baro.gender) +
     (test.state=baro.state)
        )/3 AS score
        FROM
        users AS test,
        users AS baro
        WHERE
        test.username <> baro.username AND
        test.username = '$log_username'
        HAVING
        score > 0.5";
        $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query);
        $array = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

        echo $array;

Comment: Is there an error message? Or just nothing? Are there actually some results which should be displayed, or doesn't the current user have some matches? Delete the ´HAVING...´ to display every other user, regardless of the score.

Comment: it displays nothing :s

Comment: The query looks good and works for some test data I just created. Are you sure the tested user has some matches?

Comment: hi nevermind man i fixed it now it displays it correctly :) but i got one more question off topic..  i want to change an enum of the specific user to 1 if he clicks on the submit button how do i do that ?

Comment: I don't understand your question...Just run an "UPDATE table SET row = 1" query in PHP page which gets called when the button it's clicked.